# css debug responsive height of inline block svgs within a table cell

Tags: css, svg

I need help debugging this css issue as i'm finding it impossible to solve the issue.

The css is heavy as I've posted every most of it to replicate the problem.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/) of the issue. In the fiddle you will see two identical plates. One outside a `table` and one inside a `table td`.

The plates outside the table work perfectly and responsive.

The plates inside the table td, the height of the `.char` is not 100% of parent, where is it getting it's height from?

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/

---

This is how it looks now, the `.chars` are over 100% in height.

[image]

The SVG characters `.char` are styled as inline blocks within a positioned absolute div called `.plate-chars`. See below the `.plate-chars` container highlighted in console...

[image]

This is what the plate inside table looks like now...

```
.char {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
}
```

On the front end of my site, this works at any responsive width...

Desktop...

[image]

Mobile...

[image]

If anyone could help me figure out the css conflict or missing style to fix in my supplied [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/) would be a huge help.

I'm simply trying to set the height of each SVG `.char` to 100% of the parent `.plate-chars` height.

I cannot understand where they are getting their current height from? If anyone can debug this out through the console in my fiddle, I just need to know the missing link and that would be great.

Thanks in advance if anyone can figure this out :-)

---

As an example of my frustration if I manually set the SVG `.char` class from `100%` to the actual current parent div height in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/)...

```
.plate-builder-preview .plate-standard-uk-car .front .char, .plate-builder-preview .plate-standard-uk-car .rear .char {
    height: 81.86px;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
}
```

The outcome looks sweet... but not exactly responsive

[image]

Just cant get my head around why `height: 100%;` on the `.char` SVG's is not true..?

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/

Comment: which browser? ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif chrome

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it: I would put all the letters as symbols in a different svg (the first svg element in the next example). This svg element may have width="0" height="0" and `position:absolute;left:-10em;` to throw it out of the screen

In the case of the letter U you don't need to repeat the symbol twice since You'll be using it with `<use>` and you can do it as many times you need.

Next comes the plate svg where you are using those symbols.

Please observe that the use elements have a width and a height like so: if the symbol's `viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22"` the width of the use element is `178.34` and the height is `314.22`. The x attribute value is the sum of the previous letters width.

```css
svg{border:solid;}
path{fill:black}
polygon{fill:none}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;left:-10em;">
<symbol class="char char_l" id="_l" viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.34 314.22 178.34 156.96 172.68 156.96 172.68 0 5.66 0 0 0 0 156.82 5.66 156.82 5.66 314.22 178.34 314.22"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M154.28,268.92H24.06a5.65,5.65,0,0,1-5.66-5.66V51a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66-5.66H52.37A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,58,51V224.76a5.66,5.66,0,0,0,5.66,5.67h90.59a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66,5.66v27.17A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,154.28,268.92Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_r" id="_r" viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.34 314.22 178.34 156.96 172.68 156.96 172.68 0 5.66 0 0 0 0 156.82 5.66 156.82 5.66 314.22 178.34 314.22"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M151.8,268.92H121.43a5.65,5.65,0,0,1-5.31-3.71L84.87,180.07a5.66,5.66,0,0,0-5.32-3.71H63.69A5.65,5.65,0,0,0,58,182v81.24a5.65,5.65,0,0,1-5.66,5.66H24.06a5.65,5.65,0,0,1-5.66-5.66V51a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66-5.66H109a51,51,0,0,1,51,51v28.87c0,25.86-11.1,42.27-29.21,49a5.64,5.64,0,0,0-3.26,7.24l29.64,79.91A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,151.8,268.92ZM120.31,103.61c0-12.74-7.36-19.82-19.82-19.82H63.69A5.66,5.66,0,0,0,58,89.45V132.2a5.65,5.65,0,0,0,5.66,5.66h36.8A19.82,19.82,0,0,0,120.31,118Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_1" id="_1" viewBox="0 0 76.54 314.65">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="76.53 314.65 76.53 157.32 70.87 157.32 70.87 0 0 0 0 157.32 5.67 157.32 5.67 314.65 76.53 314.65"></polygon>
    <rect class="char-letter" x="18.43" y="45.36" width="39.68" height="223.93" rx="5.67"></rect>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_4" id="_4" viewBox="0 0 178.58 314.65">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.58 314.65 178.58 157.18 172.91 157.18 172.91 0 5.67 0 0 0 0 157.03 5.67 157.03 5.67 314.65 178.58 314.65"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M154.49,221.67H141.73a4.25,4.25,0,0,0-4.25,4.25v37.7a5.67,5.67,0,0,1-5.67,5.67H103.47a5.67,5.67,0,0,1-5.67-5.67v-37.7a4.25,4.25,0,0,0-4.26-4.25H24.09A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,18.43,216V186.79a8.49,8.49,0,0,1,1.11-4.21L96.16,48.21a5.69,5.69,0,0,1,4.93-2.86h30.72A5.67,5.67,0,0,1,137.48,51V178.87a4.25,4.25,0,0,0,4.25,4.25h12.76a5.67,5.67,0,0,1,5.67,5.67V216A5.67,5.67,0,0,1,154.49,221.67ZM97.8,178.87V137.65a4.54,4.54,0,0,0-8.52-2.18L66.66,176.83a4.25,4.25,0,0,0,3.73,6.29H93.54A4.25,4.25,0,0,0,97.8,178.87Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_"  id="_" viewBox="0 0 68.08 314.73">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="68.08 314.73 68.08 157.41 62.41 157.41 62.41 0.08 0 0 0 157.32 5.67 157.32 5.67 314.65 68.08 314.73"></polygon>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_t" id="_t" viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.34 314.22 178.34 156.96 172.68 156.96 172.68 0 5.66 0 0 0 0 156.82 5.66 156.82 5.66 314.22 178.34 314.22"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M154.28,83.79H114.65A5.66,5.66,0,0,0,109,89.45V263.26a5.66,5.66,0,0,1-5.67,5.66H75a5.66,5.66,0,0,1-5.67-5.66V89.45a5.66,5.66,0,0,0-5.66-5.66H24.06a5.65,5.65,0,0,1-5.66-5.66V51a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66-5.66H154.28A5.67,5.67,0,0,1,159.94,51V78.13A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,154.28,83.79Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
<symbol class="char char_u" id="_u" viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.34 314.22 178.34 156.96 172.68 156.96 172.68 0 5.66 0 0 0 0 156.82 5.66 156.82 5.66 314.22 178.34 314.22"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M159.94,218a51,51,0,0,1-50.95,51H69.35A50.56,50.56,0,0,1,18.4,218V51a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66-5.66H52.37A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,58,51V210.61a19.82,19.82,0,0,0,19.82,19.82h22.64a19.82,19.82,0,0,0,19.82-19.82V51A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,126,45.29h28.31A5.67,5.67,0,0,1,159.94,51Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
<!--<symbol class="char char_u" viewBox="0 0 178.34 314.22">
  <g>
    <polygon class="char-jig" points="178.34 314.22 178.34 156.96 172.68 156.96 172.68 0 5.66 0 0 0 0 156.82 5.66 156.82 5.66 314.22 178.34 314.22"></polygon>
    <path class="char-letter" d="M159.94,218a51,51,0,0,1-50.95,51H69.35A50.56,50.56,0,0,1,18.4,218V51a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,5.66-5.66H52.37A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,58,51V210.61a19.82,19.82,0,0,0,19.82,19.82h22.64a19.82,19.82,0,0,0,19.82-19.82V51A5.66,5.66,0,0,1,126,45.29h28.31A5.67,5.67,0,0,1,159.94,51Z"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>--> 
</svg>



<svg  viewBox="0 0 1215 315">
  <use xlink:href="#_l" width="178.34" height="314.22" />
  <use xlink:href="#_r" width="178.34" height="314.22" x="178.34" />
  <use xlink:href="#_1" width="76.54" height="314.22" x="356.68" />
  <use xlink:href="#_4" width="178.58" height="314.22" x="433.22" />
  <use xlink:href="#_" width="68.08" height="314.22" x="611.8" />
  <use xlink:href="#_t" width="178.34" height="314.22" x="679.88" />
  <use xlink:href="#_u" width="178.34" height="314.22" x="858.22" />
  <use xlink:href="#_u" width="178.34" height="314.22" x="1036.56" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice and helpful answer for me

Comment: Not quite the fix I was after but this seems a nicer way of doing things, I just need to do some tests first with this to see if this will work for my other plates as it's a rework of what i've already got working. I need see if will work on multiple lines etc. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ah i've just had a play, and noticed the `<use>` tags are positioned on the x axis. `<use>` would be lovely to use if I could display inline block and center within svg, and go onto two lines for square plates, but not sure it can be done.

Comment: Inside svg everything is positioned absolute. You need to give the use a x value. As I've explained in my answer _the x attribute value is the sum of the previous letters width_.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I need to the characters to behave like inline characters as the user types in the input. It is the table cell that is breaking it, check this out responsively... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2wnrchLu/4/ - exactly the same css used for both plates. I'm just going to have to convert my table to a flex div table.